# Calling data with using randi command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, call

I want to call data in the matrix by using a string which is defined by 'randi' command.

```
   A=[1 2]
   B=[2 3]
   C=[3 5]

   corners = 'ABC'
   randompick = corners(randi(numel(corners)))
   disp(randompick)
   randompick(1)
```

I want as an example for A matrix:

```
   1
```

So desired result is the same as what A(1), B(1) or C(1) give. 
What's wrong in this script?
Thanks.

Comment: the same as what A(1), B(1) or C(1) give. Btw, I edited the question topic again. Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do; whilst it is possible, you should really reconsider on your approach. What has brought you to this? I hope this is not [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)(?) I

Comment: *What's wrong in this script?* `randompick` is a variable containing a character `'A'` (for example) but it is not equal to the variable `A`. The first index of `randompick` is `A` and hence is the result that you're getting

Comment: Great question! Of course it’s as Sardar said. One alternative is to not pick a variable name, but an index into, for example, a cell array and then do `data{randompick}(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you conflate *code* and *data*. `randompick` contains data, and `A` is a variable name, code.

There is a way to do exactly what you're thinking, and that involves the use of `eval`. This is not recommended exactly because it conflates code and data. This leads to complicated code that is hard to read and hard to debug. Don't do it! Fortunately there are alternatives.

One simple approach is to store your data arrays in a larger array, for example a cell array:

```
data = { [1 2]
         [2 3]
         [3 5] };
randompick = randi(numel(data))
data{randompick}(1)
```

If the name A/B/C is important, then you have yet another reason to avoid using that as a variable name. It's data! Consider, for example, using a struct array:

```
data = struct('name', {'A','B','C'}, ...
              'values', { [1 2]
                          [2 3]
                          [3 5] });
randompick = randi(numel(data))
disp(data(randompick).name)
data(randompick).values(1)
```

Yet another approach is to use a map (also called a dictionary, or hash table):

```
data = containers.Map({'A','B','C'}, ...
                      { [1 2]
                        [2 3]
                        [3 5] });
corners = 'ABC'
randompick = corners(randi(numel(corners)))
disp(randompick)
data(randompick)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments and answer. I see the difference bt code and data now.
This also works for me:

```
Z = [A ; B ; C];
r=randi([1 3])
Z(r,1)
```